# Google Colab RAM issue with semi-supervised CNN model training

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, semisupervised-learning

I'm trying to training a binary classifier by transfer learning on EfficientNet. Since I have lots of unlabeled data, I use semi-supervised method to generate multiple "pseudo labeled" data before the model go through each epoch.

Since Colab has its limits of RAM, I delete some large variables(like numpy arrays, dataset, dataloader...) in each loop, however the RAM still increase in every loop like the picture shown below.

Below is my Training loop which consists of 3 main structure: semi-supervised, training loop, validation loop.
I'm not sure which step cause the RAM to keep increase in each epoch.

(1) semi-supervised part

```
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    print(f"[ Epoch | {epoch + 1:03d}/{n_epochs:03d} ]")
    if do_semi:
        model.eval()
        dataset_0 = []
        dataset_1 = []

        for img in pseudo_loader:
            with torch.no_grad():
                logits = model(img.to(device))
            probs = softmax(logits)

            # Filter the data and construct a new dataset.
            for i in range(len(probs)):
                p = probs[i].tolist()
                idx = p.index(max(p))
                if p[idx] >= threshold:
                    if idx == 0:
                        dataset_0.append(img[i].numpy().reshape(128, 128, 3))
                    else:
                        dataset_1.append(img[i].numpy().reshape(128, 128, 3))
        # stratified sampling with labels
        len_0, len_1 = len(dataset_0), len(dataset_1)
        print('label 0: ', len_0)
        print('label 1: ', len_1)

        # since there may be RAM memory error, restrict to 1000
        if len_0 > 1000:
            dataset_0 = random.sample(dataset_0, 1000)
        if len_1 > 1000:
            dataset_1 = random.sample(dataset_1, 1000)

        if len_0 == len_1:
            pseudo_x = np.array(dataset_0 + dataset_1)
            pseudo_y = ['0' for _ in range(len(dataset_0))] + ['1' for _ in range(len(dataset_1))]

        elif len_0 > len_1:
            dataset_0 = random.sample(dataset_0, len(dataset_1))
            pseudo_x = np.array(dataset_0 + dataset_1)
            pseudo_y = ['0' for _ in range(len(dataset_0))] + ['1' for _ in range(len(dataset_1))]

        else:
            dataset_1 = random.sample(dataset_1, len(dataset_0))
            pseudo_x = np.array(dataset_0 + dataset_1)
            pseudo_y = ['0' for _ in range(len(dataset_0))] + ['1' for _ in range(len(dataset_1))]

        if len(pseudo_x) != 0:
            new_dataset = CustomTensorDataset(pseudo_x, np.array(pseudo_y), 'pseudo')
        else:
            new_dataset = []
        # print how many pseudo label data added
        print('Total number of pseudo labeled data are added: ', len(new_dataset))
        # release RAM
        dataset_0 = None
        dataset_1 = None
        pseudo_x  = None
        pseudo_y  = None
        del dataset_0, dataset_1, pseudo_x, pseudo_y
        gc.collect()
        # Turn off the eval mode.
        model.train()

        concat_dataset = ConcatDataset([train_set, new_dataset])
        train_loader = DataLoader(concat_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

i'm quiet sure the problem happened in semi-supervised part, since RAM usage did not increase when no apply semi-supervised part.

Thanks for your helps!!

Comment: Is it possible to further reduce the code necessary to show the effect? How much increases the RAM usage with each epoch relative to the total usage? Is the effect also visible if you serialize the state of the training and continue with the serialized state after a fresh start?

Comment: https://imgur.com/PVYgm7O this is the RAM when i apply semi-supervised

Comment: https://imgur.com/yLygb1z this is the RAM when i NOT apply semi-supervised part, so i'm quiet sure the problem happened in semi-supervised part

Comment: Please include the information in the question body instead of in a comment and try to reduce the code further if possible.